# How does hashing a stream of values guarantees randomness in hyperloglog?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, bigdata, computer-science, hyperloglog

From this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12327004/how-does-the-hyperloglog-algorithm-work)

`The main trick behind this algorithm is that if you, observing a stream of random integers, see an integer which binary representation starts with some known prefix, there is a higher chance that the cardinality of the stream is 2^(size of the prefix).`

Hyperloglog uses hash to achieve randomness, but how does one prove that hashing a value give random output? Or even more strictly does hash guarantees pseudo random like uniform output?

If hash does not guarantee uniform output, is there a way we can upperbound and quantize the non-uniformity of a hash function?

Comment: [Part 4: Overview of the Proof](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/75ba/51ffd9d2bed8a65029c9340d058f587059da.pdf), I think this can answer your question.